# SSH to computer with user not logged in

Tags: 12.04, ssh, password

I have two computers with Ubuntu `12.04.4` and `12.04.2`. The `12.04.2` is set up to request a password before login on start up.

When the PC is turn on I am able to connected to the `12.04.2` from `12.04.4` using SSH but if the `12.04.2` is restarted I am not able to connect.

I guess this is because the user is not log in yet in `12.04.2`.

Is there a way to connect to the PC if it is restarted and the user is not yet log in?

Comment: You have to login somehow to restart the system... also you sure the ssh server is running/installed in both systems?

Comment: @Braiam It was not running on the second machine as the user was not logged in. I need to start the `ssh` on reboot using `MortelaLCS` solution. I have found and other alternatives to do this using `crontab` with `@reboot` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is not clear for me..

I guess:

1)try to find a place that runs commands on boot up..usually in `/etc` then just write:
(you can add commans at `/home/user/.bashrc` OR `/etc/rc.local`)

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

I guess:

2)you can add ssh command connection to `.bashrc` with `sshpass` command

```
sshpass -p<password>
```

This make auto ssh connection for you.

Hope to be helpful for you